# Accidentally moved command line to desktop, command line cannot function

Tags: windows-7, command-line, directory

I wanted quick access to the command line, so I just moved the program from its normal directory to the desktop. Now when I try to open another directory "The Folder", I'm getting this error message:

```
C:\Windows\System32>cd The Folder
The system cannot find message text for message number 0x3 in the message file for System
```

Do I move it back to a certain directory, or what? 
...

Comment: Does your folder have a space? If it does use `"The Folder"`. Is the folder really located in c:\windows\system32? If not go up to c: with `cd \\`

Comment: actually, before i moved it to the desktop it used to read: C:\Users\*****> (***** being my account name). I just read somewhere that the path to the program cmd.exe was C:\Windows\System32, as for your question, no, "The Folder" isn't really located in the aforementioned path. But it's not only this simple command, it won't do stuff like the dir command, among various other things. I'm confused as to where this program actually belongs, and how its location hinders or helps its operation. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Stick it back where you found it and create a shortcut to it on your desktop instead of moving the actual .exe

Comment: You can simply change directory with `cd C:\Users\yourName`